# How to access or pass host file to Docker Python script

Tags: docker

I am using Docker to containerize a Python script. If Docker wasn't in the picture, I would want pass a file path to the script, which would proceed to work on that file.

```
python coolscript.py data.csv
```

As a Docker novice, I'm not sure sure how to accomplish this. Currently, I am automatically executing the script when the container launches.

```
docker run coolcontainer python coolscript.py data.csv
```

Since the `data.csv` file path isn't known when the image is built, its not imported into the container and I cant seem to access it. I've seen some forums saying to mount the host filesystem, but that seems overkill since I just want one file. Is there a way to just send that one file into the container at runtime? How would you be architecting this?

Comment: The file must exist inside container before execution. If you start a container without the file, it will fail and you will not be able to copy any files to it (because it is stopped).

Comment: The best option is to copy the file while building image.

Comment: Please, give more info on how you build the coolcontainer, so I could send a Dockerfile to you that will help.

Comment: It really doesnt make sense to force the file to be part of the container build since I plan on using this script for dozens of different files. I build the container with `docker build coolcontainer .`. I'm looking into mounting the host filesystem now

Comment: Alright. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -v option for bind mounts then should do the trick:

```
docker container run -v /my/host/path:/my/container/path coolcontainer python /my/container/path/coolscript.py /my/container/path/data.csv
```

Place both files in `/my/host/path`